# How to set a blank default value in iceface's selectinputdate?

Tags: java, icefaces, jspx

I use Icefaces' selectInputDate. The code in .jspx file is the following:

```
<ice:selectInputDate id="Dt" 
        value="#{actionsBean.MDate}"
        renderAsPopup="true" required="true"
        partialSubmit = "true"
        popupDateFormat="#{msgs.date_format}" 
        valueChangeListener = "#{actionsBean.mDateChangeListener}">
                          <f:converter converterId="MDateConverter" />      </ice:selectInputDate>
```

The problem actually is: I want that value in the input to be an empty string by default. I set to MDate null value, then panel opens and after user(me in this case) worked and closed panel I set null value to MDate again. But then I open the panel one more time the last value I selected via calendar was saved and automatically filled in. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you close the panel, your selectInputDate component doesn't redraw on the page, and then returns the old value. It can be, for example, if you use 'rendered=true/false' property for showing/hiding of the parent panel.

For fix, use 'visibled' property instead of 'rendered' or use binding for clear value in your selectInputDate component directly

Answer (score 0):

You may actually replace the `valueChangeListener` with `f:ajax` listener and try to see the difference.

```
<h:form id="dateForm">
....
<ice:selectInputDate id="Dt" 
    value="#{actionsBean.MDate}"
    renderAsPopup="true" required="true"
    partialSubmit = "true"
    popupDateFormat="#{msgs.date_format}">
        <f:converter converterId="MDateConverter" />      
        <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@form" 
              listener = "#{actionsBean.mDateChangeListener}">
</ice:selectInputDate>
...
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by an issue with the icefaces popup panel, what I tried is executing this code each time the popup is closed (hidden) ::

```
public void clearSubmittedValues() {
    final FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    final Application application = context.getApplication();
    final ViewHandler viewHandler = application.getViewHandler();
    final UIViewRoot viewRoot = viewHandler.createView(context, context.getViewRoot().getViewId());
    context.setViewRoot(viewRoot);
}
```

This will reset the popup's state.